# Using field not displayed in list for subsequent search

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, wxpython

I am using wx.ListCtrl to display the results of a database query. If the User then selects an Item I want to use a non-displayed field (Client.idClient) to query another table and display the result (can only be one row). The query and 'core' of the display are:-

```
sql = "SELECT Client.idClient, Client.LastName, Client.FirstName, \
        MedicalCondition FROM Client INNER JOIN MedicalCondition \
        ON Client.idClient =  MedicalCondition.idClient \
        ORDER BY Client.LastName ASC, Client.FirstName ASC, MedicalCondition

try:    
      cursor.execute(sql)       
except ValueError:
      print "Error: unable to read data"
      print("Error:", ValueError)

rows = cursor.fetchall()

self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Last Name', width = 175)
self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, 'First Name', width = 150)
self.listCtrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Condition', width=175)

 #print 'Done headings'

 n=0

 for r in rows:
       self.listCtrl.InsertStringItem(n, r[1])
       self.listCtrl.SetStringItem(n, 1, r[2])
       self.listCtrl.SetStringItem(n, 2, r[3])
       n+=1
```

My question is how can I capture Client.idClient for the subsequent search. Creating a  hidden array to hold the data seems inefficient and could potentially become quite complex as features such as paging and scrolling are added.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I would use ObjectListView instead of wx.listctrl for this. It allows you to store data in addition to what is displayed extremely easily. If clicking on an item will cause you to do another search that should be displayed in a second listctrl type widget, then that makes me recommend ObjectListView all the more. You can have the first one at the top of your frame and the second one would only appear if the user clicks an item in the first one and the search has a result.

Or you could open a second window with the ObjectListview displaying the results. The following tutorial should help you get started switching over to ObjectListView:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/

This widget was recently forked as the original is no longer maintained. See the following link for the latest version and documentation:

- http://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: This looks very useful. I will experiment with ObjectListView once I have agreement from the rest of the development team...